# Использование функции в качестве значения словаря в Enum классе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется данный код, но при запуске выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: 'CLASS' object is not subscriptable.

Как я могу исправить это?

```
from enum import Enum

def some_func():
    return 1

class CLASS(Enum):
    OBJECT = {"key" : 1, "value" : some_func}

print(CLASS.OBJECT['value']())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Члены класса-перечисления являются экземплярами этого класса

```py
>>> isinstance(CLASS.OBJECT, CLASS)
True
```

Чтобы получить соответствующее им значение, нужно обратиться к полю `value`

```py
>>> print(CLASS.OBJECT.value['value']())
1
```